# Cross - Table with frequency of categories matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, frequency, categories

I have two matrices A and B that contain integer values assigned to a category. I want to create a table `P` where `P(i,j)= p(A=i&B=j)`: Meaning that `P(1,1)` holds the probability of an element of A to be category 1 and  the same element of `B` to be category 1. Also to be clear, if you sum `P` across rows you find the frequency of categories for A matrix and if you sum P across columns you find frequency of categories for B matrix.

It is easy to execute with for-loops, but i compare huge matrices (maps with land use categories) and it is very slow as should be expected with every for-loop implementation.

Is there  a built in function in matlab or a simpler way to do this? I searched a lot but could not find something that works with matrices. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that is at least 2.5X faster than for-loops that compare element-wise A and B.
For example, 5 categories:

```
P=zeros(5)
for i=1:5
    for j=1:5
      P(i,j)= sum(sum((im1==i &im2==j))) /numel(A);
    end
end
```

if there is an even faster way (built in function) i will be very happy.